# Subscription confirmation "from" address is "do-not-reply@EXAMPLE.ORG"

Tags: drupal, subscribe

I don't see any place to change this - it looks pretty bogus, IMO.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Duh - default mailbox. Oops - my bad. Sorry.

Comment: you could make this a useful Answers to others by providing links/navigation hints

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that there is a default 'do-not-reply@...' email address.  There are these:

- fixme.domainemail@example.org
- "FIXME" info@EXAMPLE.ORG
- EXAMPLE.ORG

And in a fresh configured install (Drupal 10.2.3, CiviCRM 5.69.5, I have not come across, and certainly have not created a 'do-not-reply@...' email address.

And yet, (in a fresh and completely configured install (Outbound SMTP is working correctly) I get the following error when I try to use the https://example.org/civicrm/mailing/subscribe

> Error Mailing error: Failed to set sender: **do-not-reply@example.org**
> [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending
> email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email
> settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global
> Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: 550, response: 5.7.1 Invalid
> credentials for relay [IP address]. The IP address you've 5.7.1
> registered in your Workspace SMTP Relay service doesn't match the
> 5.7.1 domain of the account this email is being sent from. If you are 5.7.1 trying to relay mail from a domain that isn't registered under your 5.7.1 Workspace account or has empty envelope-from, you must
> configure your 5.7.1 mail server either to use SMTP AUTH to identify
> the sending domain or 5.7.1 to present one of your domain names in the
> HELO or EHLO command. For 5.7.1 more information, go to 5.7.1
> https://support.google.com/a/answer/6140680#invalidcred
> t185-20020a815fc2000000b00607cc69d4bdsm982685ywb.50 - gsmtp)]
>
> Mailing Error Unable to send email. Please report this message to the
> site administrator

This 'do-not-reply' string does not exist in the database. But it can be found in several files:

- vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/release-notes/5.43.0.md:600:- **Fixed issue with sending from do-not-reply@domain address *[maybe not]*
- vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/release-notes/5.4.0.md:522:  confirmation emails shouldn't use do-not-reply@yourdomain.org
- vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/tests/phpunit/CRM/Mailing/MailingSystemTest.php:216:      'do-not-reply@chaos.org',
- vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/tests/phpunit/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessorInboundTest.php:215:   * info@acme.com, do-not-reply@acme.com, the
- vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/templates/CRM/Admin/Form/Preferences/Mailing.hlp:15:

  {ts}Leaving this blank will use the default which will be do-not-reply@default_domain where the default_domain will be the email domain address of your default mailing account also used for bounce handling.{/ts}
- vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/BAO/Domain.php:373:    return $noReplyAddress ?: "do-not-reply@$emailDomain";

NOTE: there is no 'do-not-reply@example.com' so it appears this is being constructed likely by some of the code here.  This is beyond my scope to easily fix.

Comment: Here: civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing?reset=1; for 'No-Reply Address', is what must be configured to avoid this default email address usage.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/14133)